# Different behavior between Jupyter kernel and Python

Tags: python, linux, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've been working on a Jupyter notebook on my local, and have recently migrated it to an Ubuntu Linux VM located on a remote server. I've install Python and Jupyter on the remote server successfully, and am accessing it [via SSH portforwarding](https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh). I have been able to run other scripts and files successfully, but the script have been halting in a very strange way.

I have a large-ish pandas DataFrame (40k rows x 60 columns) that I'm pre-processing to prepare for a parallel operations, so I am slicing up the DataFrame using pandas `.groupby` and then pairing each slice with a categorical variable using `itertools.product`, with mocked example below

```
import itertools as itt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Mocked Data
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
dates = [pd.to_datetime('{}-{}-1'.format(y,m+1)) + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(0) for y, m in itt.product(
    range(2007, 2018),
    range(0,12)
)]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    index=range(0,40000),
    columns=[''.join(t) for t in list(itt.combinations(alphabet,2))[0:60]])
dataframe['ab'] = np.random.choice(dates, 40000, True)
dataframe['ac'] = np.random.choice(list(alphabet[0:6]), 40000, True)

numeric_cols = dataframe.columns[~dataframe.columns.isin(['ab', 'ac'])]
dataframe.loc[:, numeric_cols] = np.random.random((len(dataframe.index), len(numeric_cols)))

FACTORS = set(alphabet[0:15])

# Halts here! Does not finish, but no errors.
preproc = list(itt.product(
    FACTORS,
    dataframe.groupby(['ab', 'ac'])
))
```

Somehow, when I'm executing this in Jupyter as an individual cell, it simply would not complete, and just halts in the operation. The systems monitor shows that particular Python process using 100% of CPU, but not completing.

I don't think this is due to not enough processing power/memory, or code issue as I've been able to run this operation in Jupyter in my local machine, as well as as a python (i.e. `.py` file) with the same kernel on the VM.

Any help/direction is appreciated!

The specs of the remote machine and relevant versions for packages is as below:

```
OS:
Linux cooVM 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1 -Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux

Hardware:
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                8
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 44
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2400.085
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
RAM:                   16GB
```

Python 3.5.2

Pip packages:

```
Package                       Version  
----------------------------- ---------  
ipykernel                     4.7.0    
ipython                       6.2.1    
ipython-genutils              0.2.0    
ipywidgets                    7.1.0     
jupyter                       1.0.0    
jupyter-client                5.2.0    
jupyter-console               5.2.0    
jupyter-core                  4.4.0        
notebook                      5.2.2    
numpy                         1.13.3   
pandas                        0.22.0     
pip                           9.0.1       
python-apt                    1.1.0b1  
python-dateutil               2.6.1    
python-debian                 0.1.27   
python-systemd                231       
widgetsnbextension            3.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ongoing issue with Jupyter, that only occurs on Windows computers. The Github issue is tracked here:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/714